# Mailboxer ArgumentError in ConversationsController#reply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reply, mailboxer

I have tried to implement a Mailbox using this tutorial. http://www.sitepoint.com/messaging-rails-mailboxer/

My 'reply' function doesn't work well. The reply message did get posted but every time I am being shown with these errors. It didn't get directed as well.

```
ArgumentError in ConversationsController#reply
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

My current codes are as below:

conversations_controller.rb

```
def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(@conversation, params[:body])
    flash[:success] = 'Reply sent'
    redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation)
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
member do
  post :reply
end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag reply_conversation_path(@conversation), method: :post do %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= text_area_tag 'body', nil, cols: 3, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Type something...', required: true %>
</div>
<%= submit_tag "Send Message", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone advise me what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my problem.! :)

I actually also encountered the error below when debugging.

```
undefined method `mailboxer_email'
```

So I tried the following and it works. This is the how I did it.

user.rb

```
def mailboxer_email(object)
 #return the model's email here
end
```

mailboxer.rb

```
config.email_method = :email
```